# How to search the input keyword with all the fields of a table

Tags: rest, grails, full-text-search

Hi am developing my first grails application now i want to put search method in my application..  Is it possible to match the single entered keyword with all the fields of the table.Like when i use findById it will search only on id or if i use findByName it will search only on name or findByDescription find only on description..
Is it possible to use findall or findBy* to match with all the fields like id, name, description..

Comment: Check out the searchable plugin, it's a much better/faster way to search across multiple fields of a domain class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a RDBMS, you can issue a query on the following lines:

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE name like '%value%' OR description like '%value%' OR id like '%value%'
```

But this is going to be very inefficient. You can instead use a full text search API lucene/ solr and index entire content as part of one field and issue queries on that.

Comment: And as i want to render the result in XML form (since it is RESTful application) idont think i can use search API... is it possible to do the same in any other way...?

Comment: rendering the results is independent from search. Ofcourse, you can store all the fields you want to display to user as part of lucene index instead of again hitting database after the search.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the same result without using any plugins or search API.. Is possible please do inform me..

Comment: Hi i just tried with your first answer (using OR) at first it showed little error however after trial and error method it worked well thank you very much... thank you once again...